# Pausar Ciclo até Jframe fechar

Tags: java, swing

Estou a percorrer um ciclo com valores, e em cada iteracção chamo um Jframe para escolher determinados valores, o que acontece é que todas as Jframes são abertas sem que possa concluir antes a operação. No meu código o "fetchEditoras" chama o JFrame mas não espera até as operações serem concluidas e continua o ciclo. Como faço?

```
 try {
            conX3 = connection.getConnection();
            stmtX3 = conX3.createStatement();

            itens = this.getItens();
            for (int k = 0; k < itens.length; k++) {

                String sql = "SELECT * FROM ALMEDINA.YITMNET WHERE ISBN_0 = '" + itens[k] + "'";
                ResultSet rsX3 = stmtX3.executeQuery(sql);

                while (rsX3.next()) {

                     fetchEditoras(rsX3.getString("EDITORA_0"));

                }
            }
        } catch (SQLServerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SQLServerException.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
        } finally {
            conX3.close();
            stmtX3.close();
        }


public ArrayList<Editora> fetchEditoras(String editora) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    DatabaseNET connectionNet = new DatabaseNET();
    ImportX3Net connectionX3Net = new ImportX3Net();
    Connection conX3Net = null, conNet = null;
    Statement stmtX3Net = null, stmtNet = null;

    ArrayList<Editora> editoras = new ArrayList<>();

    if (connectionX3Net.getConnection() != null) {
        try {
            conX3Net = connectionX3Net.getConnection();
            conNet = connectionNet.getConnection();
            stmtX3Net = conX3Net.createStatement();
            stmtNet = conNet.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM importXNet.editora WHERE x3_name LIKE '" + editora + "'";
            ResultSet rsX3NETEditora = stmtX3Net.executeQuery(sql);

            if (stmtX3Net.getFetchSize() == 0) {

                sql = "SELECT * FROM loja_online.editoras WHERE editoras_name LIKE '%" + editora + "%'";

                ResultSet rsNet = stmtNet.executeQuery(sql);

                while (rsNet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rsNet.getString("editoras_name"));
                    editoras.add(new Editora(null, rsNet.getString("editoras_name")));
                }


                assocEditoras assoc = new assocEditoras(editoras, editora);
                assoc.setVisible(true);

                rsNet.close();
            }

        } catch (MySQLDataException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MySQLDataException.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            stmtNet.close();
            stmtX3Net.close();
        }
    }
    return editoras;
}
```

Comment: O teu problema está no ciclo while? acho que podias postar o código do teu `fechEditoras` é ai que abres o Frame e fechas sem dar tempo para completares as operações necessárias certo?

Comment: Actualizei agora, coloquei o código.

É aqui :

 assocEditoras assoc = new assocEditoras(editoras, editora);
 assoc.setVisible(true);

Comment: o problema é que ele abre uma frame por iteracção do ciclo while, não espera que a primeira Jframe feche e conclua as opeações.

Comment: Se o problema for sincronia, você pode usar a palavra reservada `synchronized` no seu método `fetchEditoras`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Creio que não é bem sincronia

Comment: Parece me uma boa solução assim o ciclo só acede pela segunda vez ao `fetchEditoras` quando a primeira concluir a sua função.

Comment: vou ler a documentação. o synchronized ficava no siclo while?

Comment: não funciona, o Jframe abre, a função continua a sua execução, mas o Jframe fica aberto, e vai continuar o ciclo porqu já executou a função.

Comment: Deve ser uma má resolução mas tenta a ver se resolve o teu problema, cria um ciclo que só sai quando o frame já nao está visível, não sei qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso, tenta usar o `.isvisivel` ou `.isactive` na condição do while e so quando devolver falso é que sai

Comment: sei pouco de java, mas com threads será que resolvia o problema?

Comment: Eu acho que ainda não percebi muito bem qual o teu real problema, mas tenho a certeza que sim, porque podias por a próxima thread só a começar quando a anterior acabar...

Comment: o meu problema é basicamento o que se queixam aqui : http://www.coderanch.com/t/338922/GUI/java/opening-multiple-frames-loop

Comment: Mas ali tem a solução, inclusive com o código.

Comment: Utilizei um JDialog em vez de um JFRAME com o seguinte ModalityType: Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL.

Acho que é a melhor solução